# Restricting access to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-account, security

I have many confidential data in my Google Drive. Also I have my google account signed in on multiple personal devices.

Since many people around me would love to get hold of these files, (and they know that it is in my Drive), I want t protect it with a pin, or even better, be asked to sign in again (even when my Drive is accessed from a device on which I am already signed in).

How do I enable this extra security feature?

Comment: Why then are you storing it in a location that other people know of? Why not use some other cloud storage services like MediaFire ?

Comment: Also if it is very very crucial that you store it in the drive, then encrypt the file and store it in the drive.

Comment: @AswinPJ Drive because i want to be able to search through all the documents and contents quickly.

Comment: Woudn't putting a pin protection on the file prevent you from searching the file? It is much of a security vs usability situation here. I would really suggest if the file is of very very crucial importance that you store it in a different cloud storage or you encrypt the file and then store it. Or you can create a different Google account and then log on to it only from a machine in which you are working on.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive doesn't include that feature. Set your device to automatically turn on the screen lock.